# How to access Multi Dimension Arrays/Arrays of Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm just trying to get into PHP and understand the core concepts, so have been messing around with arrays, jsons, etc. For this, I've tried everything, yet I cannot get to access the "Name" component of my Json. I recieve it from a CURL HTTP Request, decode it from a json then attempt to go from there. The JSON looks like:

```
[
  {
    "food1": "blah",
    "food2": "blah",
    "food3": "blah"
  },
  {
    "food1": "blah",
    "data": [

      {
        "name": "I need to access this",
        "name2": "Another name"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've tried `$Result[0]["data"]["name"]`, `$result[0][1]["data"]["name"]` and plenty more combinations of that kind of nature, yet still haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks. :)

Answer (score -1):

In your specific example you'd use `$array[1]['data'][0]['name']`

A breakdown of your array:

```php
[
  // this is the 0th element
  {
    "food1": "blah",
    "food2": "blah",
    "food3": "blah"
  },
  
  // this is the 1st element
  {
    "food1": "blah",

    // 1st element's data property
    "data": [

      // 1st element's data property's 0th element
      {

        // [1]st element's [data] property's [0]th element's [name] property
        "name": "I need to access this",
        "name2": "Another name"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: We get these types of questions every week.  We don't need to answer these.  Please close questions that ask "how to access json" or "how to access array/object" as a duplicate.  They are all snowflakes, but well covered by canonical pages.